# Question about comparing two unordered arrays and removing elements in a[] that can be found in b[]

Tags: c++, arrays

There is a problem that I can't solve it. Here are two unordered arrays

```
int a1[] = { 5, 7, 14, 0, 6, 2, 9, 11, 3 }; int n = 9;

int b[] = { 6, 4, 3, 10, 9, 15, 7 }; int m = 7;
```

I want to compare them and remove elements in a[] that can be found in b[]. The following code return a correct value of n to me. The correct value should be 4 but it give me 5 even if I successfully sorted array a1[]. It gave me a result like this:

> a1[] = { 5, 2, 14, 0 ,11 }

There is a slightly difference between my result and the model answer. I mean the order of the elements in a1[]. The model answer is

> a1[] = {5, 11, 14, 0, 2}

Can you guys help me to figure out the problem?

```
int removeAll_unordered(int *a, int& n, const int *b, int m) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (b[i] == a[j])
            {
                a[j] = a[n - 1];
                n -= 1;

            }
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement erase-remove idiom manually, any reason you do not use library function for that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the `n` error; when I run it, I get n=5. As for the order, if you want to preserve the order of the elements you must use a different algorithm.

Comment: Also, your implementation -- imagine there are a thousand elements in `a` and `b`.   You would be looping a million times.  If your going for efficiency, obviously there are better ways than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: `n` is what? the number of elements present in both?

Comment: @idclev463035818 looks like `n` is the size of `a` and it is passed as reference for function to provide new size

Comment: Also, what is the actual order the final result should be in?  Ascending?  Any order?  Original order with items removed?

Comment: OP your question is quite misleading. First you are saying that this algo provides correct value for `n` for you. Then you say it provides 5 which is not correct but it should be 4. For data provided it is not clear why you think it should be 4 as all 5 values are not in `b`. Then order of elements bothers you. What is your problem with the code? Can you make it clear?

Comment: can `a` and `b` contain duplicates? (in your example they dont and if this is always the case this could help for the solution)

Comment: Sorry about my explanation. There is one thing that I want to clarify. The n finally will be updated as number of the removed elements other than the number of elements contained in a[ ]. I want to show that the number of removed element instead of the value contained in a[ ] eventually. Initially, n is 9 in the main. In my result, there are five elements remained in a[ ] while the number of removed element in a[ ] is 4.

Comment: That is my assignment in University. Hence, I cannot use library function for that question

Comment: @LeeChatwin *There is a problem that I can't solve it.* -- To be honest with you, I still don't know what you are supposed to display, change, or return.  Your question is very confusing as to *what* the problem is.  In your question, you are changing the contents of the array in ways where you don't need to *if* all you want to know is the number of items that *will be* removed.

Comment: What I am supposed to display are the following the following things. 
( b[ ] = {6,4,3,10,9,15,7}
a1[ ] = {5,7,14,0,6,2,9,11,3} )
Removed elements in a1[ ] that can be found in b[ ]:
a1[ ] = {5,11,14,0,2}
No. of elements removed = 4

Comment: You say in the question that your problem is the *order of elements* in an array you say is *unordered* - why is that a problem?  It sounds that you have solved the problem as stated.

Comment: Yup I found that doesn't matter. @TobySpeight

Answer (score 2):

If you write code in C++ you should use what standard library provides for you - in your case `std::vector` and `std::remove_if` algo:

```
void removeAll_unordered( std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b )
{
     auto end = std::remove_if( a.begin(), a.end(), [b]( int i ) {
        return std::find( b.begin(), b.end(), i ) != b.end();
     } );
     a.erase( end, a.end() );
}
```

[Live code 1](https://ideone.com/OpF7eR)

But this usage is very inefficient, so using standard library as well which provides `std::unordered_set` aka hash set we can easily make it optimized:

```
void removeAll_unordered( std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b )
{
     auto end = std::remove_if( a.begin(), a.end(), 
         [set = std::unordered_set<int>( b.begin(), b.end() )]( int i ) {
        return set.count( i );
     } );
     a.erase( end, a.end() );
}
```

[Live code 2](https://ideone.com/foei1u)

Comment: If you use an ordinary (ordered) `std::set` (or simply sort the input vectors), then the `std::set_difference()` is available, for a simpler function.

Answer (score 2):

I found one problem in you code, I couldn't compile though, but it should work.

In your code,

```
if (b[i] == a[j])
            {
                a[j] = a[n - 1];
                n -= 1;

            }
```

When an element in `b` is found in `a`, you replace that value with `a[n-1]`, this is okay, but that value was not compared with `b[i]` as `j` got incremented, So I correct this part. If you run with different inputs you will able to catch this problem.

```
int removeAll_unordered(int *a, int& n, const int *b, int m) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < n;)
     {
        if (a[j] == b[i]) // replace a[j] with a[n-1] and decrease n
        {
           a[j] = a[n - 1];
           n--;
        }
        else
           j++; //  otherwise increase j
     }
  }
  return n;
}
```

**To get the exact answer (order of the elements in `a` after the removal)**

here is the modified code:

```
  int duplicates = 0;   //  counts total numbers that removed from a[] 

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < m;)
     {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) // replace a[j] with a[n-1] and decrease n
        {

           if (i == n - 1) // when we reach the last element of a that matches in b
           {
              n--;              //  updating length of a[] 
              duplicates++;     //  one more removed
              break;
           }
           a[i] = a[n - 1];
           n--;                 //  updating length of a[] 
           duplicates++;        //  one more removed
           j = 0;
        }
        else
           j++; // otherwise increase j
     }
  }
  return duplicates;        //  returned total removed numbers
```

Comment: Run your code with this input int[] a = { 5, 7, 14, 0, 6, 2, 9, 6, 3 };
      int[] b = { 6, 4, 3, 10, 9, 15, 7 }; And then run by my code, see the change

Comment: @Lee Chatwin, I got what yoy want, the order of elements in a, right? So, I have added a new code with my answer, Check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   Yup.... Finally, I got the a1[ ] = { 5, 11, 14, 0 ,2 }. It is same as my model answer I needed. However, the returned value of n is the same as before. n initially is a number of element remained in a1[ ]. In my execution output, I need that number to represent the number of removed elements instead of the number mentioned above. As you may know, there were initially 9 elements in a1[ ]. After removing 4 elements, we get 5 remained elements in a1[ ]. However, the returned value n is kept updating by the calling function. I have no idea to fix it. @Manoj Banik

Comment: int count = removeAll_unordered(a1, n, b, m);
 cout << "Remove elements in a1[] that can be found in b[]\n";
 printArray("a1[] = ", a1, n);
 cout << "No. of elements removed = " << count << endl << endl;
 cout << "==================================================\n";

Comment: You should be able to correct that part, I couldn't understand your question earlier. You don't need to return ' n ' as it is already getting updated as a call by reference parameter. You need to keep track of removed numbers [ here it is done by duplicates, see my edited answer ] and finally return that variables. So, I did that. Check my new answer. Let me know if it answers you question.

Comment: If it works then you can accept it as "Answer". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- I found the problem of your code. You change the variables in the for loops. First for loop use the 'n' variable for their maximum value and second for loop use 'm' value.
- Then you only decreasing n value but you didn't check the new i th value. Because now i th value changed. So, you want check again that value also. For that you can decrease 'i' value also.
- And also you mentioned above your answer is 5 not 4. Then it correct answer. Because you write this code thinking about 9 elements of the array. Not the 0 to 8. So, if you write this code thinking about 0 to 8 elements you can get whatever you want. If you want 4 you can decrease final value by one. Then you can get your value.

---

Modified cord given below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (b[j] == a[i])
        {
            a[i] = a[n - 1];
            n -= 1;
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
}

return n;
```